# Laravel task scheduling on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am new to laravel.I want to schedule some task on my application using laravel 5.3.But I still run my application on localhost.Please can someone explain me to how laravel task scheduling can be done on localhost.

Comment: First of all, read docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling
Then if you're using windows - you should have some tool like Unix's Cron and then you can add task for your job in that tool

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Windows.

Schedule a task to run **php artisan schedule:run** using the **at** command.
You also must make sure the php executable is in your system path: [How do I add my PHP directory to the PATH on Windows?](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath)

[How To Use the AT Command to Schedule Tasks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks)

Answer (score -1):

To start working with Laravel Scheduling, first, you have to run this command on the terminal.

```
php artisan make:command command_name
```

Then check the files in the directory. **App\Consol\Commnads** you'll have a command_name file. Edit as given in the following script.

```
protected $signature = 'save:file';
```

After that add your own methods and tasks to **Handle function** 
At the end, run this command to check whether the scheduling is working or not.

```
php artisan save:file
```

Comment: you didn't described laravel schduler